# How to apply layouts in a nuxt app using the layouts folder?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying out `nuxt` and having an issue with `layouts`. I created the app with the `yarn create nuxt-app` command. The versions installed are

```
"core-js": "^3.15.1",
"nuxt": "^2.15.7"
```

Inside the project directory the `layouts` folder was missing. So I created one and added a `default.vue` file. But it seems not working. I tried with adding another file `sample.vue` in the `layouts` and folder. And defined it inside `pages/index.vue` as

```
export default{
    layout: 'sample'
}
```

This also seems not working. What I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Check out your .nuxt/App.js file.
If the layout works normally, the file will contain code that uses the layout file.

Comment: so? what next. Mine contains the `import` for the default layout, but it doesn't work